# Where does phpMyAdmin store the phpMyAdmin user password?

Tags: phpmyadmin

During the setup of phpMyAdmin, a phpMyAdmin user was created and I can see the user when I look at the phpMyAdmin database privileges. Which PHP file stores the password for this user?

Comment: The config.inc.php file is not set up when installing through command line. I find your response very rude. It was announced on the phpMyAdmin mailing list that StackOverflow is where we should go for questions, and your attitude is the exact reason I felt the move was a step backwards.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Paul,
there is no such thing as a phpMyAdmin user. phpMyAdmin is a front-end for MySQL, so we're talking about MySQL users. In MySQL, users and their password are stored in a database called "mysql". 
More details at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privilege-system.html.

In phpMyAdmin's documentation, there is a discussion about different authentication modes, see http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#using-authentication-modes.

Comment: Thank you, Marc, for clearing that up. I had installed phpMyAdmin through [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~nijel/+archive/phpmyadmin) managed by Michal Čihař. It used `dbconfig-common` for an automatic setup, which included configuring a database for phpMyAdmin with random password assigned to the user, and I mistakenly thought it was a password for a phpMyAdmin configuration. All these years I've used phpMyAdmin I've never messed around with using the configuration, but I thought I'd give it a go to see how I might find it useful.

Answer (score 8):

If configured properly, phpMyAdmin creates a database and a user for this database. The database is to store visuals for the phpMyAdmin "Database Designer".

If you installed phpMyAdmin on Ubuntu through the aptitude package manager, the username and password for the phpmyadmin database is stored in plaintext in this file:

```
/etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php
```

Answer (score 1):

while installing there is no password specified for root but you can specify it to secure. when you specify it is stored as a text file in security folder of you server.
In Xampp server for windows C:>xampp>Security>mysqlrootpassword.txt

Answer (score -1):

Installed Phpmyadmin on Linux Mint 19 via a package, but the users and password would not open the installed Phpmyadmin .The file: /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php could not be opened by Vim. It is the one file that cannot be opened and with a big nasty cross at the based of the closed file. However,I found a workaround for Debian (Ubuntu, Mint, etc.) where there is a second admin account automatically generated by the system called:  debian-sys-maint. In  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
You can see debian-sys-main as user (and should not change) and its password via: sudo nano /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
I would still like to to be able to edit /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php

Comment: If you have a new question further then the one in this post please either leave a comment or make a new question to be answered. Don't ask a question as an answer.