# How do I recover the bitnami generated password from a lost system log?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

Using AWS EC2 cloud. While Bitnami generates a password in the system log on initial start up after a few times running that file is deleted. How does one go about recovering that file and therefore the password?

Comment: I've removed the `osx` and `bitnami` tags as this question doesn't apply to either.

Comment: what password are you referring to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does phpMyAdmin store the phpMyAdmin user password?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18553308/where-does-phpmyadmin-store-the-phpmyadmin-user-password)

Answer (score 1):

try typing this into your command prompt after logging into the bitnami account through SSH

```
cat ./bitnami_credentials
```